# vb.net transfer a object to multiple forms?

Tags: vb.net

I am programming in vb.net.  I am making a platformer and I made the first level and I realized, how am I gonna put all the objects into the second level!?  Please help me!

Comment: would be nice if we could see the code, have you created the first level using a class?

Comment: If you have the code exist, you should edit your question and put your code inside.

Comment: I'm building a house and I just poured the concrete. Then I realized how am I going to paint the walls? Please help me!

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Windows Forms, each form has a parent property. You can make your objects public properties on Form1 and access them from Form2 by cast ParentForm as Form1.

Additionally, you can defined `public shared` properties and fields in `SomeClass` and any code in your application can access those fields or properties. For example:

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Shared Field1 as String
    Public Shared Property Field2 as String
End Class
```

Then any form in your application can access those values without needing an object reference like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub Foo()
        Dim Param As String = SomeClass.Field2
    End Sub
End Class
```

You also can create a class in which all public members are 'Shared'. It is called a Module

```
Public Module MyModule 
    Public ModuleValue As String
End Module
```

Then anywhere in your code you can access it like this:

```
Dim Title As String = ModuleValue
```

Using a combination of these methods you can share and pass information between objects in your code.

Other Frameworks, such as WebForms, WebApi and MVC have different ways of sharing data across the application.